# reactQuery onChange request cancelation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch, react-query

I'm having trouble setting request cancelation on `useQuery` hook.
I checked documentation and tried it like this [documentation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-cancellation)
But I don't have method like `cancel()` available on `res` promise.
I changed my code to axios because I got some parser error on fetch and I did something like this:
Here's my code:

```
useQuery(['city', value], async () => {
    let cancel:Canceler;
    const promise = 
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/citiesname=${value}&_limit=1`, {
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(exec => cancel = exec),
    }) as Promise<AxiosPromise<any>> & Cancelable;
    promise.cancel= () => {
        cancel();
    }
    const res = await promise;
    setData(res.data);
},{
    enabled: value !== undefined
})
```

Can u help me with this? It's really important because I don't want to send request every single time user types something, I only want it to happen when he puts last character

So now I'm not returning data, I'm setting it to my own state via `setData` setter but it's not working, still sending request on every single change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@TkDodo's answer addresses the Javascript issue but there is an additional Typescript issue.  The react-query package is expecting you to set a property `cancel` which is not a native property of `Promise`.  So at some point we must assert that your `promise` variable is a type which has a `cancel()` method.

In the react-query package [they use](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/3d2806edb43c557be201e214edb0d503be3159f9/src/core/infiniteQueryBehavior.ts#L56) `as any` to add `.cancel` to to a promise but we can do better! The package [defines](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/2da342cde91537ef6bb8d9edfa8a967be9ef012b/src/core/retryer.ts#L33) an interface for a `Cancelable` object, but for some reason it is not exported.

```
interface Cancelable {
  cancel(): void
}
```

You can still use `async`/`await` syntax (at least from a code standpoint, this is untested so I don't know if there are any issues at runtime), but you need to assign the `Promise` returned from `fetch` to a variable before you `await` its resolution.

```
const { data } = useQuery(["city", value], async () => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    // save the promise itself, not the resolved value
    const promise = fetch(`http://localhost:8000/cities?name=${value}`, {
      signal
    }) as Promise<Response> & Cancelable;
    promise.cancel = () => controller.abort();
    // here we resolve the promise
    const res = await promise;
    const data: cityInterface[] = await res.json();
    return data;
  }, {
    enabled: value !== undefined
  }
);
```

Comment: `return data` in an `async` function will create a new promise, so i don’t think this works.

Comment: Will you be able to help me with axios?

Answer (score 3):

The difference to the example from the docs is that you are using `async / await`, while the docs are not. You are not returning the Promise where you add the cancel function to, you are returning a new Promise, create by the `async` keyword.

You need to stick to chaining `.then` in this case:

```
const { data } = useQuery(['city', value], () => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    
    const promise = fetch(`http://localhost:8000/cities?name=${value}`,{
        signal
    });

    promise.cancel = () => controller.abort()
    
    return promise.then(res => res.json())
},{
    enabled: value !== undefined
})
```